# Cursor based pagination without offset?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-cursor

For a large data set, `offset` based pagination becomes slow, and so a much quicker way is to use cursor based pagination. Basically, an anchor point, where the database knows to lookup results from that point onward. With that in mind, here is the issue I am facing:

I have a table`tv_watchers` with an autoincrementing `id`, `mins_watching_tv`, and `user_id` (20 rows total fiddle below). In this example `user_id` will be the same `1`, so no need to worry about it. We want to sort by the number of minutes spent watching tv, from highest to lowest.

This is easily done using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tv_watchers
ORDER BY mins_watching_tv DESC, id ASC
```

This will return the correct order of the 20 fields ordered as we want it in this fashion by id:

```
2, 17, 1, 16, 15, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 3, 4, 14, 19, 18
```

The issue is we want to split it up into chunks (we call them batches) of 5 since we want to return 5 results in the order above. We do this by retrieving the first 6 results, returning the first 5 to the user, and using the 6th if it exists as the cursor (anchor point) to get the next batch from:
This returns the first batch correctly:

```
-- (Batch 1) 2, 17, 1, 16, 15, 5
SELECT * FROM tv_watchers
ORDER BY mins_watching_tv DESC, id ASC
LIMIT 6
```

The 6th item here is id `5` which has a `mins_watching_tv` of `60`, so since this is the cursor we use it to get the next 6 like this:

```
-- (Batch 2) 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
SELECT * FROM tv_watchers
WHERE mins_watching_tv <= 60 OR id=5
ORDER BY mins_watching_tv DESC, id ASC
LIMIT 6
```

The 6th item here is id `10` which also has a `mins_watching_tv` of `60`, so since this is the cursor we use it to get the next 6 like this:

```
-- (Batch 3 should be) 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 3
-- (Batch 3 returns incorrectly) 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
SELECT * FROM tv_watchers
WHERE mins_watching_tv <= 60 OR id=10
ORDER BY mins_watching_tv DESC, id ASC
LIMIT 6
```

But the issue is the results that come back are not correct, it returns the incorrect batch 3 ids seen in the comment above. I am sure it has to do with the `WHERE` portion, it seems to pick up the `mins_watching_tv <= 60` part but the `id=10` part is there to let the database know to pick up results from that anchor point of 60 minutes and id 10, but that does not work correctly.

The final batch results should look like this:

```
-- (Batch 4) 3, 4, 14, 19, 18
```

I set up an [sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daa501/17) to show the issue. How can we fix the query so that it respects the cursor combination of `mins_watching_tv` in combination with the `id` to return the correct results in batches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select your first 6 like you already did, without anything in the `WHERE`.

   ```
   SELECT *
          FROM tv_watchers
          ORDER BY mins_watching_tv DESC,
                   id ASC
          LIMIT 6;
   ```
2. Duration `@duration` and the ID `@id` of the last row of the result from the previous step and put them into the `WHERE` like

   ```
   SELECT *
          FROM tv_watchers
          WHERE mins_watching_tv < @duration
                 OR mins_watching_tv = @duration
                    AND id >= @id
          ORDER BY mins_watching_tv DESC,
                   id ASC
          LIMIT 6;
   ```
3. Repeat 2. until end is reached.

Explanation:

- If `mins_watching_tv < @duration` we can be certain, that the respective row isn't in our previous result as `mins_watching_tv` is less then the minimum `@duration` from our previous result and we did a `ORDER BY mins_watching_tv DESC`.
- If `mins_watching_tv = @duration` we don't know yet if we already had the row. But as we additionally did an `ORDER BY id ASC`, we know that all rows we already had with the same `mins_watching_tv` have an id less than or equal the current maximum `@id` (per `mins_watching_tv`). So we only want those rows where `id > @id` or, as we also want the last row of the previous result repeated, `id = @id`. In short that's `id >= @id`.

As we want the union of both of those sets, we have to disjunct the above predicates, so use an `OR`. We get (parenthesis only for clarity, they're not needed):

```
(mins_watching_tv < @duration)
 OR (mins_watching_tv = @duration
     AND id >= @id)
```

And [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daa501/35/3) is the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it really helps understanding the issue better. There was a small typo in your fiddle, last line `WHERE mins_watching_tv < 30 OR mins_watching_tv = 15` should have been `WHERE mins_watching_tv < 30 OR mins_watching_tv = 30` but this is exactly the correct query needed for the cursor to function based on the duration/id combo.

Comment: @Wonka: I corrected the fiddle. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

I only skimmed but I think you just need to tweak your conditions to (for example)

`mins_watching_tv < 60 OR (mins_watching_tv = 60 AND id>=5)`